# Git: apply removed changes back to master

Tags: git

Let's say I have two branches, `master` and `a`; `a` is my working branch, and I submitted a PR to `master`, and it was merged. After, another guy removed the changes introduced by `a`.

Now, I want those files and lines introduced by `a` and removed by another programmer to be back on `master`. How can I do it? I still have `a` locally in its original state.

Comment: Revert perhaps?

Comment: Did the other person use `revert` on your commit? Do you know if they undid your changes purposefully or accidentally? And, is the stuff you wish to undo (which is an undo of your stuff), contained entirely in commits you could revert?

Comment: Without knowing the answers to my questions in the previous comment, one thing that you could do that should work either way, is to change the commit IDs on branch `a` and then remerge into `master`. For example: `git rebase master a --keep-base --force-rebase` will rewrite the commit IDs and enable you to remerge. That works from a "state" POV, but it may not be the cleanest from a Git "history" POV, since you'll have duplicate commits. Depending on what already happened, you may be able to get a slightly cleaner history by being more surgical with reverts.

Comment: @TTT The person says it was unintentional and is unsure how that happened. My only clue is the git log, which shows my changes being removed in a later merge.
The idea is to have my changes back and keep his changes at the same time.

I ended up doing this manually, but it'd be awesome to know a more proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel all of what this programmer did and only this, the best way is to perform a `git revert` onto the related commits while being on `a`, which will introduce new commits applying a negative of their changesets (just like when you want to cancel a contribution on Wikipedia and revert to previous state. Your cancel operation is seen as a new contribution on itself).

Then you submit another pull request, which will include this reverting operation, as well as the rest of your branch.

Comment: A `git revert` would undo any other changes introduced by that merge, is that right? If so, is there a way to only revert the removal of my changes and keep his changes at the same time?

Comment: Not the complete merge operation. This would only revert the selected *commit*, ie apply the negative of its changeset. Also, remember that `git revert` is not an homolog of `hg revert` (which whould rather be a `reset` instead). It's a good reason to prepare clean commits and keep them so, btw. If this single commit contains more than what you need to cancel, you still may go back one step backward keeping these changes in your index, then use `git add -p` to select what you really need.